# DBUtils: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils'

Tags: pyspark, module, dbutils

I installed DBUtils using `pip install DBUtils` but I have the error :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils'`
when trying to import :
`from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils`
in one of my script.

pip freeze confirms I have DBUtils installed :
`DBUtils==3.0.3`
but when I do `DBUtils --version` I have :
`DBUtils: command not found`

Working with Python 3.8.18 and Spark 3.3.0
What is going on here ?

I was expecting to have the DBUtils module recognized

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Wouldn't it just be ```import DBUtils```?

Comment: Any chance you are looking for dbutils from databricks? https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html